# Pathspace (PX,{x}) of well-pointed space (X,{x}) is well-pointed

Tags: homotopy-theory

It is to show, that for a well-pointed space $X$ its pathspace $PX$ is well-pointed.

$X$ being well pointed means that ${x}  \to X$ is a cofibration. Maybe someone can give me a little hint, I don't see how to use the cofibration diagram of $X$ for the cofibration diagram of $PX$.

Comment: Hint: Show that X-->PX is a cofibration. Show that a composition of cofibrations is a cofibration.

Comment: I solved it now by a lemma giving me equivalence between cofibration <-> local contraction with function from X -> I. I think we have PX with basepoint here, so only paths starting at same point x. So are you sure, that X -> PX even is a cofibration? I guess you were thinking of PX containing loops starting anywhere, so X is sent on the constant paths. I doubt this is a cofibration.